# Using CloudRun and Google SQL, will cloud run automatically use connection pooling?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Hoping somone from Google SQL/ Cloud Run can answer this question.

I am using Google SQL for hosting of my Postgres DB. I am then spinning up multiple instances of Cloud Run containers which all connect directly to the SQL DB.

My question is, will cloud Run/Google SQL automatically implement smart db connection pooling here? Or do I need to manually configure something to get connection pooling

Comment: Do you use the IP of your database or the cloud sql connector allowed on Cloud Run?Can you describe more want you mean by "connection pool"? Are you able to reuse your DB connection between several requests on Cloud Run? Is there a pool of connexion automatically established when Cloud Run run?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle your connection pooling at code level in this [Cloud SQL docuemnt](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/manage-connections) is mentioned

In the document are some code examples in various programming languages, at this time, most SQL connectors create a connection pool by default.

Cloud Run and other GCP managed services not add any pooling strategy because this could reduce the visibility for the developers.